# Django form post keyerror

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django code where I give a `POST` request. The POST variable contains the data but while trying to read it from form.cleaned_data['key'] it throws a Key error stating the key is not found. `form.is_valid()` also returns false. I am giving correct data only and it was working fine previously

my code will look like this

**views.py**

```
def open_html(request):

    form = form_main.DateForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = form_main.DateForm(request.POST)
        #print (request.POST.get('scrap_button'))
        print (form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():  # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
           #enter_time=form.cleaned_data['date']
           #enter_mail_id=form.cleaned_data['mail_id']
           #enter_timezone=form.cleaned_data['time_zone']
           print (form.cleaned_data)
           enter_mail_id = form.cleaned_data['mail_id']
           enter_date = form.cleaned_data['date']
```

**html**

```
<form  method="post">
<label >Mail ID:</label>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.mail_id}}
      <br></br>
<div id="myOutput"></div>
<label >When to send mail?</label>
    {% csrf_token %}
{{ form.date }}
<script>
    $(function () {
    $("#id_date").datetimepicker({
      format: 'd/m/Y H:i:s',
    });
  });
  </script>
```

**forms.py**

```
class DateForm(forms.Form):
    mail_id=forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    date=forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%s'])
```

Comment: What data are you tring to post? You may want to look into `form.errors` to see what caused the validation to fail...

Comment: Thanks.I am trying to post the mailid and date.I am new to django.Can you please tell me where should i add this form.errors

Comment: Please, post the code of the view you are using to render the form.

Comment: i have posted it above the views.py file. Kindly have  a look

Comment: you should print `request.POST` to check what's being posted. your question is not clear: are you getting a KeyError inside the `if form.is_valid()`? Then why do you say that `form.is_valid()` is `False`? And your html is not complete, where do your close <form>?

Comment: @MaheshwariChandrasekaran You can just  `print(form.errors)` after calling `form.is_valid()`.

Comment: @BernhardVallant Thanks for the hint i used the form.errors to get the error and solve the issue. The date format given was mismatched in views.py and html template. Thanks a lot